# how to sum true values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Ok here is an example of what I need to accomplish. I tried doing it with Active X controls but got an error. Also tried with form controls
but haven't found the correct formula to get it right.

So in basic what I want is to add up the number of unit for each order type.

So if I check the OB form control and the number of units is 40 and in the next line I check again the OB form control but this time
the number of units is 20. I want to calculate how many types I have and how many units per category.

Do I have to do it in VBA? Or with a formula I can get it done?

Thanks[unitcalculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfQop.png)

Comment: Use data validation lists instead of checkboxes and the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) or [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) function.

Comment: Your image should be included in your question as it makes easier for us to help. Also you might like to check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing duplicates from your type column (data tab in excel) then using a sumif formula [like this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). If you need to do it regularly, click record macro then follow those steps, you'll be 90% of the way there you'll probably just need to adapt the code for a variable range, give it a go/ogle